# Efficient off-screen rendering of QPainterPaths (OpenGL and non-OpenGL solution required)

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qpainter

1. In my application, I paint a street map using `QPainter` on a `widget`

   - made by `QPainterPaths` that contain precalculated paths to be drawn
   - the `widget` is currently a `QWidget`, not a `QGLWidget`, but this might change.
2. I'm trying to move the painting off-screen and split it into chunked jobs

   - I want to paint each chunk onto a `QImage` and finally draw all images onto the `widget`
   - `QPainterPaths` are already chunked, so this is not the problem
   - problem is, that drawing on `QImages` is about **5 times slower** than drawing on `QWidget`
3. Some benchmark testing I've done

   - time values are rounded averages over multiple runs
   - test chunk contains 100 `QPainterPaths` that have about 150 linear line segments each
   - the roughly 15k paths are drawn with `QPainter::Antialiasing` render hint, `QPen` uses round cap and round join
4. Remember that my source are `QPainterPaths` (and line width + color; some ***drawn***, some ***filled***)

   - I don't need all the other types of drawing `QPainter` supports
   - Can `QPainterPaths` be converted to something else which can be drawn on a `OpenGL buffer`, this would be a good solution.
   - I'm not familiar with `OpenGL` off-screen rendering and I know that there are different types of OpenGL buffers, of which most of them aren't for 2D image rendering but for vertex data.

```
Paint Device for chunk | Rendering the chunk itself | Painting chunk on QWidget
-----------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------
QImage                 |                    2000 ms |                   < 10 ms
QPixmap (*)            |                     250 ms |                   < 10 ms
QGLFramebufferObj. (*) |                      50 ms |                   < 10 ms
QPicture               |                      50 ms |                    400 ms
-----------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------
none (directly on a QWidget in paintEvent)          |                    400 ms
----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------
```

`(*) These 2 lines have been added afterwards and are solutions to the problem!`

It would be nice if you can tell me a **non-OpenGL-based solution**, too, as I want to compile my application in two versions: `OpenGL` and `non-OpenGL` version.
Also, I want the solution to be able to render in a **non-GUI thread**.

---

*Is there a good way to efficiently draw the chunks off-screen?*
*Is there an off-screen counter part of `QGLWidget` (an `OpenGL` off-screen buffer) which can be used as a paint device for `QPainter`?*

Comment: Note: I created the QImage in ARGB32_Premultiplied format. I also tried RGB32 and ARGB32 (non-premultiplied), all with nearly the same poor performance, so I guess that the problem is not "a wrong format", which was my first guess.

Comment: Is QPicture not a good choice?

Comment: I'll test the performance of QPicture and extend my question with some benchmarks: QImage vs QPicture vs QWidget::paintEvent.

Comment: QPicture is definitely not what you want, QPixmap is the preferred image class if you don't need pixel-level access.  However, if you want to render in a non-GUI thread you will need to use QImage.  For OpenGL, you could perhaps try QGLFrameBufferObject.

Comment: @DanMilburn Thanks. I will try both QPixmap and QGLFramebufferObject when I'm back home.

Comment: I'm with @DanMilburn using a plain framebuffer would be the best option, you only should require a QImage or son when it comes to the final rendering not while off-rendering. Btw how do you off-render it, could you not just make your own buffer, those are just pixel values right?

Comment: @Moss and the others: Should I prefer QImage or QPixmap for the storage of rendered chunks which will be drawn multiple times on the widget afterwards? The point is: chunks will be rendered once they got visible in the scene, and then the rendered image/pixmap will be used very often (for every scroll operation or when things appear/disappear on an upper layer)... The documentation says QPixmap should be preferred "for showing images on screen". Is this also the case when drawing it using QPainter in a paintEvent of my QWidget?

Comment: Ah and one last thing regarding the "stored format": Won't be QGLFramebufferObject the choice when I render the final widget in a OpenGL context (namely on a QGLWidget)? But AFAIK this won't be able in the paintEvent of the QGLWidget but in the updateGL or whatever the GL method is named. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @DanMilburn and the others: Can someone provide me help with QGLFramebufferObject in a chat? I can't make it working, there seems to be a problem with the OpenGL context. I found nothing really helpful on google.

Comment: (If you can't (or don't have time) to help me, I try QGLPixelBuffer, which brings its own QGLContext, but this will have a bigger overhead as far as I understand.)

Comment: Yeah! I got it working. I suggest that you, @DanMilburn, write an answer which suggests the use of QGLFramebufferObject for the OpenGL solution and QPixmap for the non-OpenGL solution. I will accept it, since your comment lead me in the right direction.

Comment: @DanMilburn Don't you want to write an answer to this question? I will then accept it ;)

Answer (score 5):

The document of [Qt-interest Archive, August 2008 QGLContext::create()](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2008-08/thread00046-0.html)

says:

> A QGLContext can only be created with a valid GL paint device, which 
>   means it needs to be bound to either a QGLWidget, QGLPixelBuffer or 
>   QPixmap when you create it. If you use a QPixmap it will give you 
>   software-only rendering, and you don't want that. **A QGLFramebufferObject 
>   is not in itself a valid GL paint device, it can only be created within 
>   the context of a QGLWidget or a QGLPixelBuffer**. What this means is that 
>   you *need* a QGLWidget or QGLPixelBuffer as the base for your 
>   QGLFramebufferObject.

As the document indicated, if you want to render in an off-screen buffer using opengl, you need QGLPixelBuffer. The code below is a very simple example which demonstrates how to use QGLPixelBuffer with OpenGL:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLFormat>
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLPixelBuffer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Construct an OpenGL pixel buffer.
    QGLPixelBuffer glPixBuf(100, 100); 
    // Make the QGLContext object bound to pixel buffer the current context
    glPixBuf.makeCurrent();
    // The opengl commands 
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glViewport(0, 0, 100, 100);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, 100, 0, 100);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glPointSize(4.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2i(10, 10);
    glVertex2i(50, 50);
    glVertex2i(25, 75);
    glEnd();
    // At last, the pixel buffer was saved as an image
    QImage &pImage = glPixBuf.toImage();
    pImage.save(QString::fromLocal8Bit("gl.png"));

    return a.exec();
}
```

The result of the program is a png image file as:

[image]

For non-opengl version using QPixmap, the code maybe in forms of below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPixmap pixmap(100, 100);
    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(&pixmap);
    painter.drawText(10, 45, QString::fromLocal8Bit("I love American."));
    painter.end();
    pixmap.save(QString::fromLocal8Bit("pixmap.png"));

    return a.exec();
}
```

The result of the program above is a png file looks like:

[image]

Though the code is simple, but it works, maybe you can do some changes to make it suitable for you.