# Qt5 more slow than qt4 for draw many pixmaps in TabWidget

Tags: c++, performance, qt

I have a widget, and I add 300 pixmaps inside.

```
MyWidget::MyWidget( QWidget *parent )
{
    setParent(parent);
    FlowLayout *flowLayout = new FlowLayout(this, 2,2,2);
    setLayout(flowLayout);

    QPixmap* cupcakes = new QPixmap("Resources/Icons/pimpCupcakes.png");
    TilePixmap* tilePximap = new TilePixmap(cupcakes, 0);
    m_buttonGroup = new QButtonGroup(this);

    int id = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<300; ++i)
    {
        TilesetButton* buttonTmp = new TilesetButton(this, tilePximap);
        m_buttonGroup->addButton(buttonTmp, id);
        flowLayout->addWidget(buttonTmp);
        id++;
    }
}
```

I had this widget in a QTabWidget like this :

```
ui.tabWidget->addTab(myWidget, name);
```

I do this operation with another widget

```
ui.tabWidget->addTab(myWidget2, name);
```

in qt4.8, creation (and first draw) need approximatively 4 secondes
and after that, switch between tab 1 and 2 is instantaneous.

in qt5, creation (and first draw) need approximatively 4 secondes (so like qt4.8)
but after that, switch tab took always 4 secondes between the time when I clicked on the tab and when the signal "currentChanged(int)" emmited.

Qt5 need add some cache configs compared with qt4 ?

(project are identic, just the Qt version is different)

Edit : 
I do the same test not with pixmap but only with QPushButton* and a simple text on it.
and it's the same problems.
3/4 sec latency between my clic and the tab switch.

I look if tabWidget code changed since qt4.8 but I saw nothing which could be the reason of this.

Comment: Perhaps you need to change your drawing algorithm? You need to make sure to not do too many operations on the UI thread at once as it will cause the UI to slow down.

Comment: maybe but, what's new on qt5, because, it's the same algorithm in qt4.8 == instant switch (redraw) and qt5 == 4secondes to switch (redraw)
with the same code/images/etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can significantly improve your performance by switching to a `QGLWidget`. Different "paint devices" in Qt have different performance, as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474078/efficient-off-screen-rendering-of-qpainterpaths-opengl-and-non-opengl-solution) question, the fastest possible solution is to use a `QGLWidget` with a `QGLFramebufferObject`.

Also, I think `setParent(parent)` is not needed, `QObject` takes care of that and `QWidget` inherits `QObject`.

Also, unrelated, but still, the correct term would be "slower" not "more slow".

Good luck!

Comment: In my widget, I'm using QPushButton (MyPushButton) with a specific treatment and graphics (I used a css files for design)
how use QButton (they have all one QPixmap on it) in a QGlWidget ?

Comment: I agree with the QGLWidget approach. This will significantly improve drawing performance and application responsiveness.

Comment: @MathieuT - just use `QGLWidget` instead of a regular widget and everything you put in it will automatically draw using OpenGL. Your push button will work the same way, QPainter has both a software (what you are using right now) and hardware (OpenGL) implementations.

Comment: Ok thanks ! It works, I have just a black color under my background color. I need to fix it.
Thanks guy !